# Set up eclair wallet 0.3.1 but cannot send onchain funds

Tags: wallet

I filled my wallet with some btc then wanted to send coins onchain and it seems there is no that possibility ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like onchain send functionality is not implemented yet. Workaround until then is to import the 24-word seed into another wallet. This can be run in parallel with eclair without problems.

Comment: thats the problem. seems I have incorrectly written seed. and I need to transfer out coins from this wallet and more carefully write seed.

Comment: Well that sucks. If it is a significant amount of BTC, you can still set up a full lnd node on a RaspiPi or a PC, and send the funds there via lightning channel.